# Setting width of container returns unexpected result in React-Native for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a container `<View style={styles.container}>` in which is a `<FlatList />`.
An element rendered by the `<FlatList />` is a card, styled like this

```
  card: {
    borderColor: 'green',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderTopRightRadius: 7,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 7,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 7,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 5,
    width: '100%',
    height: 290,
  },
```

There is snack here https://snack.expo.dev/90GJaJuPw

Now, there are two problems.

1. Why is `<View style={styles.thisAffectsCardWidth} />` not horizontally in the `center` of the card?
2. Why is the the width of the card `<View style={styles.card} />` getting larger, when one adjusts the `width` of `thisAffectsCardWidth` from e.g. `50% to` 100%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try removing `alignItems: 'center'` from the contentContainerStyle and add `width: '100%'` Eg: `contentContainerStyle={{ width: '100%' }}` and add `alignItems: 'center'` to the card styles.

https://snack.expo.dev/@charinda04/forlorn-cereal

2. Since you haven't set the contentContainerStyle width of the flatList, Width changes with *thisAffectsCardWidth* width.

Comment: The snack you provided does not solve the problem. It contains the same code as my snack.

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@charinda04/forlorn-cereal

sorry I have attacked the wrong link